# How to manually perform the changes made by sysprep?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a backup of the Windows 7 operating system made on a totally different hardware than the current one, which I can not start the operating system and I need to start it.

For this reason, I need to make the changes that sysprep performs manually, but I do not know if it is possible since I have not found any documentation of the changes made in the file system and / or registry.

What changes should I make in the file system to start the operating system in the new Hardware?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of Backup? What was the backup created in and what format is it in now?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a work around to get your system booting.  It will not do, nor is it intended to do the work of sysprep.

1. You need to connect this hard drive to another working PC.
2. Then you need to modify the drivers for the hard drive.

Obviously change the drive letters and paths as needed.  You will need to extract the drivers until their INF files are visible.

1. The Microsoft **Deployment Workbench** can help you extract the necessary drivers.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54259
2. If you have a spare hdd you can install windows, and all drivers. Make a backup copy of **C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository** to USB or etc.  Then change hdd back, and point the below command to the location of said backup copy.

You should try `dism /image:f:\ /add-driver /driver:c:\drivers`

The F: refers to the non-bootable copy of windows,connected to a working PC, as c: will be the current working copy.

If that fails manually editing the registry, not fun.
You can change the hard drive controller to "Standard IDE....", but doing it manually won't be easy.

Note: All drivers will be wrong

If you can get it to boot, I recommend making a backup copy.
Then sysprep the original, and if it sysprep works keep that copy.